# NCHAR alternative in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I need to count the number of characters in a string, in `R` we use `nchar`, what is the alternative function in `sparkR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`length`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/length.html):

```
 Welcome to
    ____              __ 
   / __/__  ___ _____/ /__ 
  _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/ 
 /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version  2.2.1 
    /_/ 


 SparkSession available as 'spark'.
> df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(s=c("foo", "foobar")))
> head(select(df, length(df$s)))
  length(s)
1         3
2         6
```